# Create URL with /#/ in path and open in safari

Tags: ios, swift, url, firebase-dynamic-links

I use firebase dynamic links which contain an URL to our webapp.
If the dynamic link is opened, the deep link is fetched.
So far so good. As we use the /#/path pattern in our webapp to redirect a user to different sections, we have a problem now, creating such an url in our iOS application after we have to append a new parameter in the url

If this example URL is in our dynamic link

```
https://domain/#/main/page?utm_source=app&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=testcampaign
```

i get it and have to append a parameter for autologin mechanism in our webapp.

So here is the point where i fail at two different approaches.

1. Getting the string from the url and appending the token parameter and value.
   This approach works fine until I have to parse the urlString back to an URL object. The /#/ inside causes an error when creating a new URL object. 
   I try to replace /#/ with /%23/ (encoded #), but this does not work on our ngnix / webapp infrastructure.
2. Appending the token parameter with new URLQueryItem in URLComponents.
   This approach leads to a wrong URL resulting in (token is the added parameter)

   ```
   https://my-stage.bikersos.com/?token=tokrenvalue#/main/premium?utm_source=app&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=testcampaign
   ```

I append the URL Query Item with this extension

```
extension URL {
  func addQueryParams(newParams: [URLQueryItem]) -> URL? {
    let urlComponents = NSURLComponents.init(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    guard urlComponents != nil else { return nil; }
    if (urlComponents?.queryItems == nil) {
        urlComponents!.queryItems = []
    }
    urlComponents!.queryItems!.append(contentsOf: newParams)
    print(urlComponents!)
    return urlComponents?.url
  }
}
```

does anybody has an idea how I could solve this problem? I personally prefer the second approach, if it is possible to append the parameters at the end

Comment: Is using a `#` like that even a valid URL?

Comment: okay, strange findings. I dont know why, but now I am able to append a new parameter with the string to url conversion method from approach 1 without any error. But does anybody know, why the URL params appending extension ads them before the /#/ part?

Comment: Because what you have is an invalid URL. The `#` is a reserved character that indicates the start of the `fragment` portion of the URL, which is always at the end.

Comment: so this would be the correct definition of the url as a string? https://domain?utm_source=app&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=testcampaign/#/pathinfo
this cannot be added as a deep link in firebase :-/

Comment: Yes, although I don't know if `/` is a legal token to have after the `#`. You would have to check the specification of URL, laid out in [RFC 1738](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how it has to be done with firebase and utm parameters (this link can be added as deep link in a dynamic link for firebase)

```
https://example.domain.com/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=button&utm_campaign=testcampaign#/path1/subpath?webappparam1=1&webappparam2=asdf
```

This way all utm parameters are applied and the path will be available in the web application too.

You can add new query params using the iOS SDK but be aware, they are added at the utm parameters location.

If you need to add them at the end, check if there already exists an ? in the path and write your own appending at the end of the url.